# Struggling with the meaning of discrete.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, integers

Even though the set of all integers is infinite, is it still discrete?  Also, is a finite set of decimals, such as the following set of $3$ decimals $\{ .1, .2, .3\}$ discrete because it's members are finite, separated and countable?

Comment: Its *elements* are discrete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any set with the property that for every element of the set there is an open set containing a singleton element of the given set is discrete. For the set of integers, the open set containing $\left(a-\frac12,a+\frac12\right)$ contains only one integer ($a$), so it is discrete. Any finite set is discrete (take the length of interval to be minimum of the distances between the elements). Set of all rational numbers are not discrete under the usual topology (because they are dense in $\mathbb R$).

Comment: Does a set have to be finite to be discrete?

Comment: No, @GuyOnInternet, I've written that the set of all integers is also discrete.

Comment: OK.  This clears things up a bit.  From your answer I gather that all finite sets are discrete, except not all discrete sets are finite.

Comment: Yes, that is true.